# 1) how to write excel to memorystream....2) how to download excel file from browser....using Micosoft.Office.Interop.Excel and c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, serialization, export-to-excel, memorystream

```
//i'm using VS 2008, dll as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
//sample code..
Excel.Application xlApp;
Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;

object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;                
xlApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();                
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);//create new work book
xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

//CREATING ONE Rectangle shape
xlWorkSheet.Shapes.AddShape(MsoAutoShapeType.msoShapeRectangle, 47, 24, 500, 90);
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Shape[] myShapes = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Shape[1];
 //adding textbox
 myShapes[0] = xlWorkSheet.Shapes.AddTextbox(MsoTextOrientation.msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 75, 60, 70, 30);
myShapes[0].TextFrame.Characters(misValue, misValue).Text = "Tracking";
```

//download option from browser.

```
context.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename= report.xls");
```

//here i'm using temporary text file.but i need without using temporary file..

```
string file = context.Server.MapPath("new.txt");
 Byte[] myByte = File.ReadAllBytes(file);

  context.Response.Clear();
  context.Response.BinaryWrite(myByte);
  context.Response.Flush();
  context.Response.Close();
```

Can we use Ipersiststream interface to save the objects in memorystream ?

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/csharp/2/10101323/how-to-implement-ipersiststream-interface-in-c.aspx

Comment: Do not do this! The Office Automation libraries are designed to be used inside of a desktop application. They will fail in many different ways if you try to use them from an ASP.NET application.

Comment: @ani: don't use any of that from ASP.NET, period.

Comment: It's super easy to do this with xlsx files - they are XML. You can output the XML and put the content type as excel 2007 files. If you have a nicely formatted excel file to start with, you can save it as xml and open it in notepad - it will preserve all formatting code.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an interest in creating an Excel document with more formatting than the GridView can do you may want to take a look at EPPlus:

http://epplus.codeplex.com/

The library is capable of creating Excel files with the ability to customize cells, formats, etc.

If the GridView works for you, go for it, but if not there are other Excel options. You should be able to save the content to a memory stream and output the memory stream to the browser.

Here is a sample of a FileResult handeler that I've used with ASP.NET MVC. The concept can be applied to WebForms, all it does is write out to the response stream. My class has a property for the datatable to load (this.dataTable) and the file name you want the browser to download the file as (fileName) and the work book name (this.workBookName)

```
    protected override void WriteFile(HttpResponseBase response)
    {
        using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage())
        {

            ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(this.workBookName);

            ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(this.dataTable, true);

            response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
            response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=" + fileName);
            response.BinaryWrite(pck.GetAsByteArray());

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am completely agree with John Saunders, may be you should try this way.

Bind the dataset to GridView and then download it to excel.

Use below segment of code to get the value from the control

```
private static void PrepareControlForExport(Control control)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < control.Controls.Count; i++)
        {
            Control current = control.Controls[i];
            if (current is LinkButton)
            {
                control.Controls.Remove(current);
                control.Controls.AddAt(i, new LiteralControl((current as LinkButton).Text));
            }
            else if (current is ImageButton)
            {
                control.Controls.Remove(current);
                control.Controls.AddAt(i, new LiteralControl((current as ImageButton).AlternateText));
            }
            else if (current is HyperLink)
            {
                control.Controls.Remove(current);
                control.Controls.AddAt(i, new LiteralControl((current as HyperLink).Text));
            }
            else if (current is DropDownList)
            {
                control.Controls.Remove(current);
                control.Controls.AddAt(i, new LiteralControl((current as DropDownList).SelectedItem.Text));
            }
            else if (current is CheckBox)
            {
                control.Controls.Remove(current);
                control.Controls.AddAt(i, new LiteralControl((current as CheckBox).Checked ? "True" : "False"));
            }

            if (current.HasControls())
            {
                PrepareControlForExport(current);
            }
        }
    }
```

Now Create a method which will download the data from gridview.

```
private void ExportX()
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; Filename = ExcelReport.xls"));
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
        StringWriter stringWrite = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);
        Table table = new Table();

        //  include the gridline settings
        table.GridLines = GridView1.GridLines;
        if (GridView1.HeaderRow != null)
        {
            PrepareControlForExport(GridView1.HeaderRow);
            table.Rows.Add(GridView1.HeaderRow);
        }
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            PrepareControlForExport(row);
            table.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        if (GridView1.FooterRow != null)
        {
            PrepareControlForExport(GridView1.HeaderRow);
            table.Rows.Add(GridView1.FooterRow);
        }

        table.RenderControl(htmlWriter);
        Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());
        Response.End();
    }



public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
    {

    }
```

That's all you need to do, call the above method to download the data.